# Как сделать проверку отдельных символов переменной?

Tags: java, типы-данных

Написал код по проверке румынского СНП (аналог кода паспорта).
Там каждая цифра вычисляется по формуле, я сделал ввод кода через пробел, чтобы проверять числа, можно ли сделать так что бы код писался целой строкой, а не через пробел каждую цифру и при этом что бы была проверка, нужная часть кода под Фибоначи начинается:

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Calculator {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          
    
            System.out.println("Input 13 СNP numbers, and put whitespaces after each number. After press ENTER:");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s1 = sc.nextLine();
            String[] split1 = s1.split("\\s+");
    
            int q = Integer.parseInt(split1[0]);
            int w = Integer.parseInt(split1[1]);
            int e = Integer.parseInt(split1[2]);
            int r = Integer.parseInt(split1[3]);
            int t = Integer.parseInt(split1[4]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(split1[5]);
            int u = Integer.parseInt(split1[6]);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(split1[7]);
            int o = Integer.parseInt(split1[8]);
            int p = Integer.parseInt(split1[9]);
            int s = Integer.parseInt(split1[10]);
            int d = Integer.parseInt(split1[11]);
            int f = Integer.parseInt(split1[12]);
    
            if (f == (q * 2 + w * 7 + e * 9 + r * 1 + t * 4 + y * 6 + u * 3 + i * 5 + o * 8 + p * 2 + s * 7 + d * 9) % 11 && f != 1) {
                System.out.println(true);
                //CNP Румынии
                //прописал дополнительное условие так как если по формуле сумма равна 10, то в CNP будет последняя цифра 1, а в остальных случая последняя цифра равна той, что выходит из формулы
            } else if (f == 1 && (q * 2 + w * 7 + e * 9 + r * 1 + t * 4 + y * 6 + u * 3 + i * 5 + o * 8 + p * 2 + s * 7 + d * 9) % 11 == 10){
                System.out.println(true);
            } else {
                System.out.println(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Какое отношение фибоначи имеет к вопросу? Если никакого, то удалите эту часть из кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, разумеется. Замените свой сплит `String[] split1 = s1.split("\\s+");` на такой `String[] split1 = s1.split("");`

Но это как-то странно и сложно выглядит. Может как-то так попробовать:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    
    private final static int [] OPERATION_NUMBERS = {2,7,9,1,4,6,3,5,8,2,7,9}; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Input 13 СNP numbers, and put whitespaces after each number. After press ENTER:");
        System.out.println(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
    }
    
    public static boolean check(String cnpNumbers) {
        try {
            final String[] args = cnpNumbers.split("");
            if (args.length != 12) return false;
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < OPERATION_NUMBERS.length; i++) 
                result = result + OPERATION_NUMBERS[i] * Integer.parseInt(args[i]);            
            int f = Integer.parseInt(args[12]);
            return (f == result % 11 && f != 1) || (f == 1 && (result) % 11 == 10);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне нужно было как раз понять, как перебирать числа в строке а не по отдельности, гуглил и не мог найти нужный ответ, спасибо огромное

Comment: @Oleksandr Kostopravov не за что. тестируйте внимательно, потому что я написал на быструю руку и даже не запускал. удачи